# Android web view control programmatically

Tags: android, webview

We are loading an HTML form (with text boxes and some other form control) in a web view in our android application. The HTML files are stored locally in the device. There is a submit button in the HTML form which invokes a restful POST api to save the details to the server.

Is there any way to control the values of text boxes in the HTML form pragmatically? For example, user opens the screen with webview and entered some values. And user taps on the home button of the device. And then again user taken back the application from the background. Still the webview is loaded, but we want to erase the values of the text boxes in the web view when it is loaded from the background. Is it possible in Android?

Comment: you can do those using javascript but make sure you have enabled javascript in your webview

Comment: another approach would be to to use webview.loadURL in your onResume() method of your webview that way every time the app launches from background the content will be shown again. Tell me if this doesnot work

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried this, but how can we access, for example clear a text field, in a html page from android onResume() ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to proceed is to reset the webview when the OnResume method is called (when the activity from background goes to foreground).

So, please call the `webview.loadURL` under the onResume() section on the webview activity.